# How to remove or change local git repository though command line

Tags: git

I am quite new to git. When I type `git init` it starts the repository in C:/Users/Ioanna/.git/
I tried manually deleting the .git file from this folder, and it said this:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Ioanna/.git/
```

I want my git repository to be in another custom file I made. How can I achieve this through the command line? Where can I set where my git repository should be?
I need to know, if I don't want a folder to be a repository anymore, and I want to remove git, is it enough to only remove the .git folder ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding git init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525629/understanding-git-init)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.git` folder with `rm -r .git/`

You have to go into your working directory (for example `cd /c/Users/Ioanna/projects/superprogram/`), then perform the `git init` command there.

This will create a new `.git` subfolder (`/c/Users/Ioanna/projects/superprogram/.git/`), which will contain the repository information and history. You can safely ignore it as long as you do not interfere with it.

Comment: I tried the rm -r .git/, but I faced the following problem:
rm: cannot remove '.git/objects/4b': Directory not empty

Comment: It could come from filesystem caching or another issue like a semaphore not released; it unfortunately happens too often on windows. Try `rm -rf .git/`, or after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Git repositories track all the files on a specific folder.

When you do a `git init` the current folder becomes a git repository and git will start tracking files in that folder.

If you want to track one file then create a new folder, move all the files you want to track in there, `cd` into that folder and do a `git init` there.