# Create git repository with code already written on my local machine

Tags: git, github

I've written my React code on my local machine but since I'm the only contributor. Now I want to share it on my GitHub. How can I create a repository with the already written code?

I tried to create a repository on my machine with the same name as the already existing folder but then it just wants to replace the existing folder so I'd lose all the code.

Comment: `git init` inside the directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding git init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525629/understanding-git-init)

Comment: And then just add, commit and push?

Comment: When you create an empty github repo (no readme, no template, no license), you will get instructions: [[screenshot of empty repo](https://daily-dev-tips.com/ezoimgfmt/cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image/upload/v1635140780469/XtUegZPbD.png?ezimgfmt=rs:743x423/rscb2/ng:webp/ngcb2)]

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple comments already mentioned `git init`, but here's the full process:

1. `git init` in the repository folder
2. If you're going to use a [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) (so that certain file names or patterns are never part of the repo), this is the best time to create it - it will be painful to get rid of those files later
3. `git add` all your files
4. `git commit`
5. On GitHub, create an empty repo (do not create any files there yet)
6. Back on your own system, `git remote add origin` and then the SSH or HTTPS URL provided by GitHub
7. `git push origin main`

This will all be detailed when you create the repo on GitHub, BTW.

Comment: Remember to create a gitignore, if necessary, *before step 2*. Once you have the build files in your repo, it is much harded to get rid of them. Examples for different frameworks are [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: Thanks @TorgeRosendahl - that's an excellent point. .gitignore is never retroactive!